# creating a type consisting of a subset of int and float'

Tags: f#

Suppose I wanted to represent ONLY these 8 temperatures:

```
98F
99F
100F
101F
37.0C
37.5C
38.0C
38.5C
```

I would have a type such as :

```
type Temp = 
  | F of int
  | C of float
```

Perhaps rather than using `int` and `float`, I would use more specific types?

**How do I create a type that will ONLY allow 8 different temperatures?**

Comment: Are you performing calculations with these values?

Comment: @phoog no i am not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you are extremely confident that you only will ever require 8 temperatures, you could do something like this:

```
type AllowedTemperatures = 
            | F98
            | F99
            | F100
            | F101
            | C370
            | C375
            | C380
            | C385
```

That said if you want to instead use your type `Temp`, this cannot be done easily as it basically requires the ability to have [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which is a feature F# doesn't have (though apparently there's a [package](https://github.com/jackfoxy/DependentTypes) that I haven't tried that attempts to add this to the language). You could try with ssomething like this:

```
type Temp = 
  | F of int
  | C of float with
  static member fromInt value =
    if value <> 98 && value <> 99 && value <> 100 && value <> 101 then
        raise <| System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("value")
    else
        F value
  static member fromFloat value =
    if value <> 37.0 && value <> 37.5 && value <> 38.0 && value <> 38.5 then
        raise <| System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("value")
    else
        C value
```

And always construct your discriminated union members via the static members. But this won't prevent someone from directly calling the constructor.

EDIT: Thanks to the suggestions from AMieres, one way to make it less likely to call F incorrectly would be to shadow over the constructors in `Temp`. For example, you could do something like:

```
type Temp = 
  | F of int
  | C of float



let F value  = 
    if value <> 98 && value <> 99 && value <> 100 && value <> 101 then
        raise <| System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("value")
    else
        F value
```

However, someone could still call `Temp.F`.

Comment: ouch. that looks really messy

Comment: I believe the `||` in your `fromInt` and `fromFloat` methods should all be `&&`, else the condition will *always* be true (and an exception will be raised) no matter the value. After all, if the value is 98, it isn't 99, and so on.

Comment: Also if you define `let F = if ...` and `let C = if ...` then it would always perform the validation before creating the values

Comment: @AMieres would you mind showing me? i think i understand

Comment: @l--''''''---------'''''''''''' I believe he's saying to shadow over the `F` constructor. However, someone could still just call `Temp.F` directly.